# How to split an array dynamically on the basis of keywords?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, split, highlight

I have an array(prop1) and also a set of keywords(prop2). I want to be able to split the array as per the keywords so that it looks like the wordSet array. How do I split this? The number of words in prop1 and prop2 can vary.

```
prop1 = {"Hello  World. I want to welcome you to my kingdom"}
prop2 = ['World', 'welcome', 'kingdom']


const wordSet = 
[
  "Hello ",
  "World",
  ". I want to ",
  "welcome",
  " you to my ",
  "kingdom"
]

arr.map((wordSet) => {
  const isHighlighted = prop2.indexOf(wordSet) > -1;
  return <span className={isHighlighted ? classes.highlighted : classes.other}>{wordSet}</span>
})
```

Comment: It's kind of unclear at the moment. Would you like to elaborate please?

Comment: My bad, I've updated the paragraph. Is it clear now?

Comment: Wait, you mean `prop1` string? Yes, it's clear! 

Comment: Yes, prop1 is basically a  complete paragraph which I want to split on the basis of the keywords in prop2, as seen in wordSet

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve it! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd construct a regular expression from the `prop2`s - make a RE that matches any characters until running into the keywords, and separately capture the matched keyword:

```js
const prop1 = "Hello  World. I want to welcome you to my kingdom";
const prop2 = ['World', 'welcome', 'kingdom'];
const pattern = new RegExp('(.*?)($|' + prop2.join('|') + ')', 'gi');
const wordSet = [...prop1.matchAll(pattern)]
  .flatMap(m => [m[1], m[2]])
  .filter(Boolean);
console.log(wordSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do multi pass using split. I am not sure if it will work out well, but let me give a try!

```js
var str = "Hello  World. I want to welcome you to my kingdom";
var arr = ['World', 'welcome', 'kingdom'];
var final = [str];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  final = final.flat(2).map(function (f) {
    return f.split(arr[i]).join("aaaa" + arr[i] + "aaaa").split("aaaa");
  }).flat(2).filter(a => a);
}

console.log(final);
```

There could be possibly the `aaaa` might be a part of the word or the array, that's the only caveat I have got here. But we can switch it using something like this:

```js
var str = "Hello  World. I want to welcome you to my kingdom";
var arr = ['World', 'welcome', 'kingdom'];
var final = [str];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  final = final.flat(2).map(function (f) {
    // Not fool proof.
    var sep = str.indexOf("aaaa") > -1 ? "bbbb" : "aaaa";
    return f.split(arr[i]).join(sep + arr[i] + sep).split(sep);
  }).flat(2).filter(a => a);
}

console.log(final);
```